# Numerical Range of an Operator and Infinite Curvature

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, operator-theory

Let $T$ be an operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and recall that the numerical range of $T$ is defined as $W(T) = \{\langle Tx,x \rangle \mid ||x|| = 1\}$. Here is a theorem I'm reading:

> If $\lambda \in W(T)$ is a boundary point at which $\partial W(T)$ has infinite curvature, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Question: What exactly does it mean for $\partial W(T)$ to have infinite curvature at $\lambda$?

Comment: I suspect it means that the boundary has a sharp corner, like at a vertex of a polygon. Or at an edge of a polyhedron.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Is there any way of making this rigorous?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what definition your source is using. There are several variations on the concept of curvature.